# Is this function periodic ? $f:[-30\pi,30\pi] \to [-1,1]$ $f(x)=\sin x$?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

> Is this function periodic ? $f:[-30\pi,30\pi] \to [-1,1]$ , where
> $f(x)=\sin x$

Now , obviously $\sin x$ is a periodic function , I am asking this question just because according my to definition of periodic function :

A function $f$ is said to be periodic if for some constant P , it is the case that
$$f(x+P)=f(x)$$ fo all values $x$ in the domain.

Now if I take $x=29\pi$ (which is in the domain of the function) , then I must have $$f(29\pi + 2\pi) = f(29\pi)$$ or , $$f(31\pi)=f(29\pi)$$ But this is not the case as $f(31\pi)$ is not defined .

So, I concluded that the given function is not periodic.

Could someone please let me know whether I am right or not , and if not , where did I go wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: In the definition $x+P$ must be in the domain as well, otherwise $f(x+P)$ is not defined.

Comment: Using that definition of periodic (which is what I usually do) no function can be periodic on a finite interval.

Comment: And using @Gibbs 's defintion all functions on a bounded interval are periodic, just choose $P$ big enough.

Comment: I am not giving any definition. I am just saying that the definition of periodicity written like that does not make much sense if $f(x+P)$ is not defined. And what you say is not true. Take $f(x)=x$ defined on $[0,1]$. Since $f(x+P) \neq f(x)$ for $P \neq 0$ then $f$ cannot be periodic for any $P$.

Comment: I'd say this was periodic with period $2\pi$ in the sense that $f(x)=f(x+2\pi)$ whenever $x$ and $x+2\pi$ are within the domain: that is it extends to a $2\pi$-periodic function on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The definition I used is the same one which is given on Wikipedia

Comment: @ARROW then your function cannot be periodic, because e.g. $f(31\pi)$ is not defined.

Comment: @Gibbs So according to you , is it right to say  that any function with a finite domain can not be periodic ?

Comment: I guess you mean bounded domain. Assume $f$ defined on $[a,b]$ has period $P>0$, and take $x=b-P/2$. Then $f(x+P) = f(b+P/2)$, which is not defined, and thus $f(x) = f(x+P)$ is not defined as well, contradiction.

Comment: @Gibbs , yes I meant bounded domain , but I didn't clearly understood which direction are you pointing towards , are you saying that functions with bounded domain can be periodic or they can't be ? Because this contradiction doesn't clearly tell me what are you trying to prove.

Comment: I am assuming a periodic function on a bounded domain exists. Then I find a contradiction. So there are no periodic functions on bounded domains. I just wanted to give you a more formal argument towards this conclusion (you should consider more general domains for a general argument).

Comment: @Angina Seng , when both $x$ and $x+2\pi$ are in domain then no doubt it is perfectly periodic but the problem is , what when they are not ? And I don't think that extending the given domain to R is acceptable , as there is no sense of restricted domain then.

Comment: @Gibbs , I perfectly get your point now , and it's clear now . Maybe you should have posted it as an answer though . Thanks a lot for your time !